# Printing significant figures regardless of decimal point

Tags: r, rounding, standard-error, significant-digits

The table below (mean ± se) contains true data that will be presented in a publication. As you can see, the data has a very wide range. Using R, I rounded all numbers to 3 significant figures, but I want to include trailing zeros as well as zeros to the left of the decimal point as significant to try to keep the table tidy. So basically I want ALL numbers, on either side of the decimal point, zeros included, to be considered significant, so that only 3 digits are printed regardless of the number. Is this possible? I have tried `signif`, `round`,`sprintf`,`options()` and `formatC`, without success.
These results were obtained using `x$summary = paste(signif(x$Value, digits=3), "\u00b1", signif(x$se, digits=3))`

```
35.2 ± 3.13 > this is good
124 ± 14.8 > this is good
196 ± 6.53 > this is good
1.34 ± 0.0505 > I would like this to become 1.34 ± 0.05
0.0443 ± 0.00386 > I would like this to become 0.04 ± 0.00
123 ± 0.0067 > I would like this to become 123 ± 0.01
```

Comment: What are you starting with? Right now they're strings, not numbers. You can convert back with `strsplit` and `as.numeric` if you need. Also, what does your desired output look like?

Comment: Appears ambiguous. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: @alistaire I edited the question to help clarify

Comment: If `x` is a character vector of the existing means and errors, using `purrr` just because, something like `strsplit(x, ' ± ') %>% map(as.numeric) %>% map(round, digits = 2) %>% map_chr(paste, collapse = ' ± ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `gsubfn`.  In the pattern we select the numbers including the dots (`[0-9.]+`), and replace it by first converting to `numeric` (`as.numeric(x)`), and then `round` it.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("[0-9.]+", ~round(as.numeric(x), 2), v1)
```

In addition to the `round`ing, we remove the extra characters with `substr`

```
gsubfn("[0-9.]+", ~substr(round(as.numeric(x), 3), 1, 4), v1)
```

Or using `sprintf` to format the `round`ded numbers and then replace the extra trailing zeros with `sub`.

```
sub("\\.0+\\s|0\\s", " ", gsubfn("[0-9.]+", ~sprintf("%.2f", 
        round(as.numeric(x), 2)), v1))
#[1] "35.2 ± 3.13" "124 ± 14.80" "196 ± 6.53"  "1.34 ± 0.05" "0.04 ± 0.00" "123 ± 0.01"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("35.2 ± 3.13", "124 ± 14.8", "196 ± 6.53", "1.34 ± 0.0505", 
                    "0.0443 ± 0.00386", "123 ± 0.0067")
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. But try as I might, I cannot get it to fit into the script I was using to generate a table from SummarySE. Can you offer any advice to substitute your code (the second one work best) into this line `x$summary = paste(signif(x$Value, digits=3), "\u00b1", signif(x$se, digits=3))`

Comment: @JCon Here we are dealing with `x$summary` i.e. sub(...., gsubfn(....., x$summary))`

Comment: thank you, I figured it out. Would you mind explaining your answer briefly? I never would have come to this conclusion alone...

Comment: @J.Con  I added some description.  Hope it helps.